# How to download a file with MSYS?

Tags: msys

I would like to download a script from a vanilla MSYS environment.

On Linux, I would do

```
wget <url>
```

On Mac OS X, I would do

```
curl -O <url>
```

Unfortunately, neither of these alternatives appear to be available in a default installation of MSYS. I have also tried using the `LPW::Simple` module in Perl, but that also seems to not come installed by default.

Are there any tools that come with a default MSYS environment that can be used to accomplish this?

I could always tell the end-user to download the file themselves, but that defeats the goal of having everything "just work" with a minimal need for installing additional software.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an MSYS wget package, but it doesn't seem to be installed by default.  If you are willing to modify the MSYS environment, your script can do:

```
mingw-get install msys-wget-bin
```

Comment: id downloaded the package but didnt install it.. how could i manally install it